# How to align the last element on the right when using \hfill?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, datatool

I am making a wine list from a CSV file (see my first question here: [How to import data from excel and format it as text in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451030/how-to-import-data-from-excel-and-format-it-as-text-in-latex/451812?noredirect=1#comment1135825_451812)) and I need to align the prices on the right.

To do this, I used the `datatool` package to fetch the informations from my spreadsheet, `\DTLforeach` to iterate what I wanted to do and `\hfill` to align my prices on the right. (see code after the picture)

As you can see on the picture, it worked very well for every line but the last one of each (subsub)section, which is slightly misaligned:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Pour modifer les marges
\usepackage{geometry}
% Marges du document 
\geometry{hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm}


% To remove the heading of the table of contents ("Contents")
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother %%% WAS \makeatotherx = ERROR %%%

% To make itemized lists
% This package provides user control over the layout of the three basic list environments: enumerate, itemize and description. It supersedes both enumerate and mdwlist (providing well-structured replacements for all their funtionality), and in addition provides functions to compute the layout of labels, and to ‘clone’ the standard environments, to create new environments with counters of their own.
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Datatool package to load external files (csv)
\usepackage{datatool}

%--------------------------%

\title{Carte des Vins}
\author{B}
\date{\today}

%--------------------------%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

%--------------------------%
\newpage
\section{Bordeaux} 

% Load CSV database (here bordeaux.csv)
% and give it a label (here BOR)
\DTLloaddb{BOR}{bordeaux.csv}

    \subsection{Red}
%%%%%%% CUT CODE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage

            \subsubsection{Saint-Julien}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Iteration for Bordeaux Red Saint-Julien (R03)
\DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\Region}{R03}] % Condition
 {BOR} % Database label
     {\Vintage=Vintage,\Name=Name,\Classification=Classification,\Type=Type,\Origin=Origin,\Region=Region,\CostPrice=CostPrice} % Assignment
{% Stuff to do at each iteration:
\begin{itemize} %%% ABSENT IN MY ORIGINAL CODE %%%
    \item[]
    \textbf{\Vintage}
    \textbf{ \Name}
    \textit{ \Classification}
    \hfill\CostPrice
\end{itemize} %%% ABSENT IN MY ORIGINAL CODE %%%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        \subsubsection{Margaux}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Iteration for Bordeaux Red Margaux (R04)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CUT CODE%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

How can I align all my prices on the right?

**Excerpt of my CSV file:**

```
CODE,Vintage,Name,Classification,Origin,Size,Type,Wine,Region,Stockholding,CostPrice,TOTCostPrice,TOTCostPriceBis
GRUAUD LAROSE,1971,Château Gruaud-Larose,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,2.0, £15.00 , £30.00 , £30.00 
LALANDE BORIE,2011,Château Lalande-Borie,,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,35.0, £19.70 , £689.50 , £689.50 
RESERVE LEOV-BARTN,2011,La Réserve de Léoville Barton,,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,12.0, £20.86 , £250.32 , £250.32 
CLOS DU MARQUIS,2004,Clos du Marquis,,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,3.0, £35.83 , £107.49 , £107.49 
GRUAUD LAROSE,2005,Château Gruaud-Larose,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,16.0, £43.49 , £695.84 , £695.84 
DUCRU BEAUCAILLOU,1978,Château Ducru-Beaucaillou,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,2.0, £56.52 , £113.04 , £113.04 
LAGRANGE 3EME SJ,2005,Château Lagrange,3ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,6.0, £58.75 , £352.50 , £352.50 
LEOVILLE POYFERRE,2000,Château Léoville Poyferre,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,2.0, £73.33 , £146.66 , £146.66 
GRUARD LAROSE,1986,Château Gruaud-Larose,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,1.0, £100.00 , £100.00 , £100.00
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code as shown can't be run (a good [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) for LaTeX should start with `\documentclass` and should have a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` pair, in this case it would also help if you could supply example `.csv` data, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), so I can only guess that you are missing a `%` somewhere.

Comment: Oh yes sorry. :x I added my preamble so the code should be readable now.

Comment: The CSV file appears not to have come through. Just add the first few lines of `bordeaux.csv` to the question, so we have something to play with.

Comment: My CSV spreadsheet looks like this:   
Vintage / Type / Wine / Name / Classification / Origin / Region / Size / CostPrice  
Vintage is the year.   
Type says if this is a red, white or sweet white wine.   
Wine says if this is a Bordeaux, Burgundy, Port or Rest of the World wine.  
Name is the name of the wine.   
Classification is the award (ex: 2ère Grand Cru Classé).  
Origin is the village.  
Region is the region of the wine.  
Size is the size of the product (bottle / half / magnum).  
CostPrice is the price of the product.

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner on this site, still trying to format my comment properly.

Comment: Please add an excerpt of the `.csv` to your question. A `.csv` file is just a normal text file, you can open it with your favourite text editor and copy and paste the first five lines, say. Don't add it in the comments. You don't need to explain the data to me, you just need to show a bit of data we can play around with. I tried to run your example with data I made up and got several errors. Can you please check that you don't get these errors or remove them?

Comment: I did compile your document here... Have you noticed you are getting lots of compilation errors? You really shouldn't ignore these. Your code is doing an `\item` without being wrapped in a list environment (and this is adding a space after the last entry). Try adding `\begin{itemize}` before the `\DTLforeach` command and an `\end{itemize}` after it. The output should look right then. Ooh, and you have a typo. You have `\makeatotherx`, with an extra `x`.

Comment: I get two kinds of errors: (1) `! Undefined control sequence. l.28 \makeatotherx`. It should have been `\makeatother` instead. (2) `! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.`. This is because you have `\item[]` in your code when there is no `itemize` or `enumerate` to make use of it. That causes an error.

Comment: @moewe I mainly get 2 types of errors when running my code, but it doesn't affect the compilation, I still get the PDF: 
**1)** Undefined control sequence. (l.15) `\makeatotherx` (no "Contents" in the heading of the Table of Contents).  
**2)** LaTeX Error: Lonely \item -- perhaps a missing list environment. (at the end of every iteration) It corresponds to the `}` at the end of each `\DTLforeach` sequence. (I'm not sure I'm using the vocabulary correctly).

Comment: Yes, but errors *must* be fixed even if superficially they don't affect the PDF - the absolutely affect the output. TeX has a limited ability to recover from errors, but usually it has to guess what to do and that is rarely exactly what you intended to happen. (1) Replace  `\makeatotherx` with `\makeatother`. (2) Either don't use `\item` at all or wrap it into an `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}`.

Comment: The problem is, if I remove the \item[] in my code I don't get a list but a bunch of text...

Comment: Ok I modified my code, I'll change it in my question.

Comment: no space shows if you follow @moewe advice to add `itemize` environment to wrap around the entire contents of subsubsection Saint-Julien

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two obvious problems with your code. You get errors about both of them.

Firstly you mistyped

```
\makeatother
```

as `\makeatotherx` which causes LaTeX to complain

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.22 \makeatotherx
> ```

Secondly your loop code in `\DTLforeach` calls `\item` but there is no surrounding list environment that would know how to deal with it.

Since you want to use `\item` to get a new line, I suggest a plain `trivlist` in this case.

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bordeaux.csv}
CODE,Vintage,Name,Classification,Origin,Size,Type,Wine,Region,Stockholding,CostPrice,TOTCostPrice,TOTCostPriceBis
GRUAUD LAROSE,1971,Château Gruaud-Larose,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,2.0, £15.00 , £30.00 , £30.00 
LALANDE BORIE,2011,Château Lalande-Borie,,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,35.0, £19.70 , £689.50 , £689.50 
RESERVE LEOV-BARTN,2011,La Réserve de Léoville Barton,,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,12.0, £20.86 , £250.32 , £250.32 
CLOS DU MARQUIS,2004,Clos du Marquis,,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,3.0, £35.83 , £107.49 , £107.49 
GRUAUD LAROSE,2005,Château Gruaud-Larose,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,16.0, £43.49 , £695.84 , £695.84 
DUCRU BEAUCAILLOU,1978,Château Ducru-Beaucaillou,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,2.0, £56.52 , £113.04 , £113.04 
LAGRANGE 3EME SJ,2005,Château Lagrange,3ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,6.0, £58.75 , £352.50 , £352.50 
LEOVILLE POYFERRE,2000,Château Léoville Poyferre,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,2.0, £73.33 , £146.66 , £146.66 
GRUARD LAROSE,1986,Château Gruaud-Larose,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,1.0, £100.00 , £100.00 , £100.00 
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
\section{Bordeaux} 
\DTLloaddb{BOR}{bordeaux.csv}
\subsection{Red}
\subsubsection{Saint-Julien}

\begin{trivlist}
\DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\Region}{R03}] % Condition
 {BOR} % Database label
     {\Vintage=Vintage,\Name=Name,\Classification=Classification,\Type=Type,\Origin=Origin,\Region=Region,\CostPrice=CostPrice} % Assignment
{% Stuff to do at each iteration:
    \item[]
    \textbf{\Vintage}
    \textbf{ \Name}
    \textit{ \Classification}
    \hfill\CostPrice
}
\end{trivlist}

\end{document}
```

Possibly a table (`tabular`) would be a better fit.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the problem in the code, the root issue is that `\CostPrice` always has an ending space, as one can see by using `\texttt{\meaning\CostPrice}+++`.

[image]

This comes from the fact that your csv data has spaces before the commas, as `datatool` doesn't trim leading or trailing spaces.

> Note that spaces count in the usual TeX manner and won’t be trimmed
>   from either side of the separators. (p. 46 of the `datatool` user manual)

Thanks to @NicolaTalbot who kindly pointed it out in a comment.

Here is an excerpt of your data file:

```
GRUARD LAROSE,1986,Château Gruaud-Larose,2ème Grand Cru Classé ,Saint-Julien,Bottle,Red,Bordeaux,R03,1.0, £100.00 , £100.00 , £100.00
```

where the spaces show around the monetary items.

With the following (from @moewe's comment to OP)

```
\begin{itemize}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Iteration for Bordeaux Red Saint-Julien (R03)
\DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\Region}{R03}] % Condition
 {BOR} % Database label
     {\Vintage=Vintage,\Name=Name,\Classification=Classification,\Type=Type,\Origin=Origin,\Region=Region,\CostPrice=CostPrice} % Assignment
{% Stuff to do at each iteration:
    \item[]
    \textbf{\Vintage}
    \textbf{ \Name}
    \textit{ \Classification}
    \hfill\CostPrice
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{itemize}
```

there is no problem

[image]

The extra space doesnt show then. (it is suppressed by item paragraph)

Remark: in fact even with your buggy code you could have avoided the sapce this way:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Iteration for Bordeaux Red Saint-Julien (R03)
\DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\Region}{R03}] % Condition
 {BOR} % Database label
     {\Vintage=Vintage,\Name=Name,\Classification=Classification,\Type=Type,\Origin=Origin,\Region=Region,\CostPrice=CostPrice} % Assignment
{% Stuff to do at each iteration:
    \item[]
    \textbf{\Vintage}
    \textbf{ \Name}
    \textit{ \Classification}
    \hfill\CostPrice
}%<----- suppress space from line end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Because then there is only ONE not TWO space tokens at the end of paragraph. Of course much better is to wrap in `itemize` else `\item` is illegal.

Comment: `datatool` doesn't trim leading or trailing spaces. (p. 46 of the user manual: "Note that spaces count in the usual TeX manner and won’t be trimmed from either side of the separators.")

Comment: @NicolaTalbot ok! (if you ever need it, `xinttools` has `\xintZapSpaces` which in two expansion steps removes leading and trailing spaces of its argument `#1`; you need some `\expandafter` if `#1` is `\Foo`, to unpack its contents, so typically `\oodef\FooStripped{\expandafter\xintZapSpaces\expandafter{\Foo}}` where `\oodef` is `xint`'s lingua for two expansions) (page 174 of `xint.pdf` doc)